# Qt Designer: How to fix screen size disparity

Tags: qt, scaling, qt-designer

I'm working on a program in QT Creator as well as in QT Designer. This is my first experience with the QT family, and I've been working on this for about 3 weeks now. I have to design a variety of menus for a study I've been assigned to make this thing for.

I'm using the QT Designer / QT Creator built-in drag-and-drop to make the biggest pieces and then using code to change some things during runtime (some rich text labels change after user input, for example). My problem is that I'm working on a two-monitor setup. One monitor is 1920 by 1080, and the other is 3840 by 2160. When I drag the running program from the 1920/1080 screen to the other, the sizing just goes all to hell. Text in the LineEdit gets cut off and often the labels just get screwy.

I'm using the "QT Widget Application" project as a base in QT Creator and all of the UI forms are .ui files, NOT .qml files. I have a substantial portion of this already done, so I need to either keep everything in .ui while fixing this or find an easy way to convert to a better format AND fix the problem.

What's very weird is that QT Designer's preview screen of the form looks the same on both screens. I can drag the main menu preview between the 1920/1080 screen and the 3840/2160 screen and there's only very minor changes. Meanwhile the running program in QT Creator has massive disparities in appearance depending on the screen.

Here's a picture to hopefully explain it better, visually:

[image: the image.]

These are just two print-screens, cropped down to show one of the things that's changing. The top half is the running program, and the bottom half is the preview, both on the same screen at the same screen size (maximized). I've tried changing the horizontalStretch and verticalStretch for various elements in the Designer but it's still borked.

This is probably a rookie problem, but I am in fact a rookie with QT. I'm just trying to make sure that no matter what screen size we run this thing on, it looks the same no matter what.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like a problem related to widget [themes](https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-5.10/gallery.html) in Qt.

Qt Designer shows you the form preview using the fusion style, but when you run your program Qt will select the best match for your platform. This could explain the differences that you see. You can override this behavior forcing the fusion style.

Edit: Another thing that you can try is to enable the Hi-DPI screen support for rendering, if not set yet.
Just add this line to your main function like this:

```
QApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling);
QApplication::setStyle(QStyleFactory::create("Fusion")); // these lines before the next
QApplication a(argc, argv);
```

You will need to add `#include <QStyleFactory>` on top to make it work.

Comment: This did not fix the issue. Put that in exactly the correct spot with the include at the top and the window is still radically changing. I haven't hard-coded any resizing handlers or anything, so I'm at a loss as to what is causing there to be such a disparity between the behavior of the preview versus the running program. Is there any way for me to try and 1-to-1 copy the settings for the preview?

Comment: No, there is no preview settings that you can inspect or copy. What about your DPI settings? Do you use custom dpi settings? Also what  os an what qt version are you using?

Comment: I haven't changed any of the DPI settings. Like I said, I just started a vanilla project and have been using the very basic settings that it sets me up with. I'm using Windows 10 (Professional, I think). I downloaded the most recent versions of QT Creator and Designer as of three weeks ago, so I have Creator 4.9.1 and Designer 5.13.0.

Comment: see my last edit... this is my best guess for this evening... Hope it helps :)

Comment: This did work, thank you so much. I will clarify, however, that the style factory line is unnecessary, at least for my problem. (In fact, for some reason it made the radio buttons on one of my widgets disappear.) The `QApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling);` line was all I needed to fix things. You're a life saver!

Comment: Glad that it worked :) honestly I have no clue for the issues with the fusion theme. Be aware that if use stylesheets to style your app, you could notice differences on different os. Anyway if that's not a concern, there is no need to investigate furhter.

Comment: Where do you add those lines? immediately after `from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QDialog, QApplication` ?

Answer (score 2):

For anyone who's facing the same issue and using PyQt. Here's the solution.

```
os.environ["QT_AUTO_SCREEN_SCALE_FACTOR"] = "1"
app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
```

You just need to set an environment variable :)